# background image in smaller resolution

Tags: html, css

I have a big background image with x1600 width. It suit perfectly in 1600x900 screen. However when i change it to 1280x720, the right background image is trimmed. Making the centered slideshow aligned to the right.

How do i make it trim on both side left and right while remaining the slideshow to be centered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
background-position: center center;
```

That will position the background in the middle, and if the screen isn't big enough then it will trim on all needed sides.

Bear in mind, though, that my 1920x1200 screen would get empty edges.

Comment: Hi, then what would be the best idea to handle this situation? I read through Keeping a CSS background image the same regardless of user resolution.. but thsi would making the slideshow to be even smaller if it remain the size.. as my background image has the border for the slideshow.. please advice

Comment: Fading the edges of your image out to transparency (or to match the background color behind it) should keep it from looking bad.

Comment: Or alternatively, making it repeat across the width seamlessly

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
background-position: center center;
```

to center the image.

```
background-size: cover;
```

will scale the image to it's largest size, so that both it's width and height fit inside the area,

```
background-size: contain;
```

will scale the background image so all of it is visible, and

```
background-size: 100% 100%;
```

will stretch the image to area's width and height.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp

Hope that helps!

EDIT: For compatibility with older browsers, specify the same value with `-moz-background-size`, `-webkit-background-size`, and `-o-background-size`.
See [background-size - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/background-size).